# Regex program not catching exception, other problems

Tags: c++, regex, g++

When I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

main () {
    const string source = "hello(abc_def)";
    const regex regexp("he(l)lo.*");
    smatch m;
    if (regex_match(source, m, regexp)) {
        cout << "Found, group 1 = " << m[1].str() << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    }
    const regex regexp2("hello\\((\\w+)\\)");
    try {
        if (regex_match(source, m, regexp2)) {
            cout << "Found, group 1 = " << m[1].str() << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Not found" << endl;
        }
    } catch(const exception& exc) {
        cout << "Got exception: " << exc.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
Found, group 1 = el
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
   what():  regex_error
```

accompanied by a dialog box that the program is crashing.  I'm using g++ on Windows, 4.8.1 (yes, I specified `-std=c++11`), and I realize that the regular expression stuff was still experimental until 4.9, so that could explain why the first capture group is wrong and why it might have had a problem with the second regex.  I'm still concerned about why it said it was throwing `std::regex_error` but my code didn't catch it.  Changing `exception&` to `regex_error&` in the `catch` clause didn't change the behavior.  Are all of these just library bugs, or did I do something wrong?  I'm trying to relearn C++ after not having used it for 15 years or so (and also trying to learn C++11), so I'm concerned that I might have done something dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs in this line:

`const regex regexp2("hello\\((\\w+)\\)");`

And this line is not inside a "Try-catch" block.

Comment: OK, thanks.  It looks like a dumb error on my part---but on the other hand, the on-line C++ references I found don't even mention the possibility of throwing regex_error, let alone tell me at which point it will be thrown, so I couldn't really tell.